# Entity Framework : How can I recreate tt records from and edmx file...does the lack of tt records cause could not find conceptual model error

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have been working with some database first entity framework development against an exisiting database and lots of stored procedures.  When I was doing my development I would get tt files created and these were causing conflicts with the edmx file.... I forget the exact message but many of the generated classes where being found twice.   When trying to solve this problem I found that if I deleted the tt files it clear the problem up... and did not appear to have any down side with this.

My code is working and all is good.

But now I have gotten far enough along that others are trying to use my code for the first time... They get the code out of the repository and I am finding that on every machine but my original development machine the code compiles fine, but when attempting to run I am getting an error of
"Could not fidn the concetual model for type xxxxx"...  I know this is related to the Entity Framework and in reading I am beginning to think this is being caused by not having the tt records on the other machines....

I don't know why it works on my machine and not others....Is it because I deleted the tt records?  If so How can I generate new tt records from the edmx file?   I have looked and not found anything on how to correct my mistake....

The second question is how can I keep the tt records and the edmx file from conflicting?  My memory is that the tt records would create file...but then when I would update the edmx file it would start creating conflicts .... like the edmx and the tt records would out of sync...and the tt records were not being updated when the edmx file was.

This is all still development code....I am now looking at trying to do code first EF...I had read about this, but didn't think I could take advantage of it as ALL of the business logic is stored in stored procedures so I was going the database first route....  But this is not working as there are tons of GETS each of which has a slightly different set of attributes.... From what I have seen the database first works, but I am getting a whole lot of different classes when what I really need is a base class...maybe with optional or nullable values... and in same cases a full hierachy of classes... so now I am just now starting to read up on code first EF with using an existing database (which I hope supports stored procedures).

Comment: I may be able to answer your first questions when I see your project, which I don't. I'd guess that something has not been checked in. As for the third question: I doubt if you should use EF at all. The classes should match the output of SQL queries, that's basically it. Do you also use SPs for CUD actions?

Comment: I could strip off the areas (which hold specialized business logic) and post the project....the edmx is in the main model....but I don't see any way to attach files on this site ... As for the second question ... the PRE-EXISTING SPs have some CRUD and lots of other specialized calls that are best suited for a repository pattern (or service layer)

Comment: I asked "CUD" because you may consider using [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) for dynamic reading (R) of your sprocs and EF mapped to the database _tables_ for CUD, see [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

Comment: I had heard of that...I will look into when I get back to work.

Comment: Re-reading I see I did not answer your question...I am porting a 2-tier system over to asp.net mvc...originally with a data first Entity framework layer...As a 2-tier system EVERYTHING is a stored procedure sometimes returning multiple datatables in a complex dataset....which is one of the challenges of using entity framework.  For the first cut of redevelopment I can not move away from the SPs...I will only be allowed to do this piecemeal after the new website is proven and up and running....but my goal was to isolate the SP layer behind full data models / Repository pattern.